# How to write a scikit-lean estimator with different predict results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to wrap a new method called "[GEMSEC: Embedding with Self Clustering](https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/GEMSEC)" in a model class that conforms to scikit-learn's conventions.

I read about predict function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-predict) and it seems like predict function must return an array of `[n_samples,]`or `[n_samples, n_outputs]`.

The model I'm implementing does two different things: Learning embeddings (representation) and clustering and I don't know what to return from my the predict function to be suitable for `predict` functions as defined by scikit-learn.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you split that into two separate estimators?

Comment: @Dan, I can't. I'm about to write a wrapper to an existing code that does the two tasks simultaneously. I edited the question